# How to pick variables in vars.tf from BASH script

Tags: bash, terraform

I am provisiong an EC2 instance using Terraform. It also has a startup script. I have vars.tf where I have specified all the variables in it. In my bash.sh script it should pickup one variable from vars.tf

Is it possible to refer the variable in vars.tf from bash script? Below is my use case.

**bash.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

docker login -u username -p token docker.io
```

**vars.tf**

```
variable "username" {
  default = "myuser"
}

variable "token" {
  default = "mytoken"
}
```

My bash script should pick the variable from vars.tf

If this is not possible any workaround?

Comment: It is unfortunate that Terraform uses its own format for these things. If you can't find an existing parser, you'll have to write your own.

Comment: Is this bash script, user data to be run by cloud init? If so, yes, you can just build your script with those variables rendered in the template using the [templatefile](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile) function.

Comment: This question was wrongfully closed. The correct answer would be to use a [templatefile](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile) with which would be possible to pass variables to the script provided from a `vars.tf` file.

Comment: Yes, I can understand @tripleee's confusion, but this probably shouldn't have been closed out of hand as the marked duplicate is for the opposite of what is being asked here.

Comment: a simple solution could be to use terraform output. Create an output and just add the variable to them. In your bash script, you can then use something like MYVAR=$(terraform output myoutput)

Comment: I would also agree that is the correct answer, so if either of you want to write it up, then we can solve this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to provide Terraform variables to a script, we can use [`templatefile`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile) function. This function reads to content of a template file and injects Terraform variables in places marked by the templating syntax (`${ ... }`).

First we want to create a template file with the bash script and save it as `init.tftpl`:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker login -u ${username} -p ${token} docker.io
```

When creating the instance, we can use `templatefile` to provide the rendered script as user data:

```hcl
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = "ami-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  user_data = templatefile("init.tftpl", {
    username = var.username
    token    = var.token
  })
}
```